# ubuntu 12.04 switch window does not change language

Tags: language-support

I used to work with ubuntu 10.04, in which every window retained the selected language. So if I where to write in english in one window and in another language in some other window, switching back and forth using alt+tab would keep the windows each in its own language

I have now installed 12.04 but I see that the language setting affects all windows. Is there a way to toggle this behavior?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the `Keyboard layout` settings and choose the option

```
Allow different layouts for individual windows
```

[image]